React useEffect - Running continuously in browser
I am new to React. I have a GET API. First I will load in ueEffect.
Whenever I am calling that my browser showing that API is running infinite time.
I did something in the useEffect dependency by providing wrong function . But I don't know how to stop that. Added screenshots below
This is my useState that holds the data:
const [loadData, setLoadData] = useState([]);

This is my async function I am setting my state in:
const fetchData = useMemo(() => async => {
  try {
    const responseData = await axios.get(baseUrl { withCredentials: true })
    const details = await responseData.data;
    setapiLoading(false); //loader false
    if (details.length === 0) {
      setLoadData(null);
    }
    else {
      setLoadData(details);
    }
  }
  catch (error) {
    toast.error( error + ':Please try again', { position: toast.POSITION.TOP_CENTER })
  }
}

useEffect(() => {
  fetchData();

}, [fetchData]);

In this image, the effect is running forever:

How can I solve this? Need to stop running infinite. Thanks in advance.

your fetchData() has no condition. inisde useEffect, check if if details are there, if not then call fetchData()

Is fetchData used anywhere else in your component, or just in that effect?

@AdamJenkins only in this function

my loaddata inside dependency is running infinite

FYI: If you are using IntelliJ Community (based on your original screenshots), and cannot afford/want the Ultimate version; I recommend using VS Code to edit web code. You will have a much better experience.

Your code example appears to be incomplete, but a quick glance says you are missing the useMemo hook's dependency array, so it's not actually able to memoize and provide a stable fetchData reference to the useEffect hook. Use the useCallback hook instead and pass a proper dependency array or move your fetchData function declaration into the useEffect hook callback body to remove it as an external dependency.

The effect runs every time fetchData changes. The reference to fetchData changes every time loadData changes. So, the effect runs every time loadData changes (continuously).
To fix it, put everything inside the effect so it only runs once on mount:
useEffect(() => {
  const fetchData = async () => {
    // your function
  }
  fetchData();
},[])


You should change your use Memo to a useCallback where you're defining your fetch data:
const fetchData = useCallback(() => async => {


you also need to pass your dependency array at the end
so full example will be like this:


const fetchData = useCallback(() => async => {
    try {
        const responseData = await axios.get(baseUrl { withCredentials: true })
        const details = await responseData.data;
        setapiLoading(false); //loader false
        if (details.length === 0) {
           setLoadData(null);
        }
        else {
          setLoadData(details);
        }
     }
     catch (error) {
       toast.error( error + ':Please try again', { position: toast.POSITION.TOP_CENTER })
     }
, [])


the reason why it running infinitely because you pass loadData as a dependency to useMemo() for fetchData. as a result, every time you calling setLoadData(), useMemo will return new instance of fetchData, which subsequently triggers useEffect().
Here is how you can solve it by defining fetchData inside useEffect:
   const [loadData, setLoadData] = useState([])
   useEffect(() => {
      async function fetchData() {
        try {
          setApiLoading(true);
          const responseData = await axios get(baseURL, { withCredentials: true });
          const details = await responseData.data;
          if（details.length === 0) {
            setLoadData(null);
          } else {
            setLoadData(details);
          }
        } catch(error) {
          toast.error( error + ':Please try again', { position: 
  toast.POSITION.TOP_CENTER });
        } finally {
          setApiLoading(false);
        }
      };

      fetchData();
   }, [])


